# How to get dailymotion videos list

Tags: android, video, dailymotion-api

I want to get list of videos from daily motion, i have registered in daily motion. it's retrieved **API key** and **secret key** but i have no idea what is the next step, i want to show the list of videos and show the detail.

I have referred https://developer.dailymotion.com/api but i could not find any way how to integrate in my application.

Please guys help to solve this!!!

Comment: did you get any Json from Response?

Comment: no actually i have no idea how to pass it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to get videos only (no channel or playlist) You can simply do:

```
 https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?page=2
```

Response will be paginated so you need to add page numbers

```
 https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?page=2
```

You can also get more >10 results

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?limit=100
```

Comment: Just click these links and you can see the response in the browser :)

Comment: how do u get the top ten videos (sort them by views?)

Answer (score 1):

Set up Retrofit and Moshi/Gson (Best Guide: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) and then it would be just calling an endpoint.

```
@GET("https://api.dailymotion.com/channel/music/videos")
Call<List<Video>> getVideos();
```

or

```
 @GET("https://api.dailymotion.com/user/{userId}")
 Call<List<Video>> getVideos(@Path("userId") String userId);
```

And to use the Access Token:

```
@GET("https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?")
 Call<List<Video>> getVideos(@Path("userId") String userId, @Query("sort") String sort);
```

Comment: but how to pass id like
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x26ezrb
in this link x26ezrb is id, so i can get this id?

Comment: but how to get userId?

Comment: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#auth See this. I would suggest first setup retrofit and get list of videos (because you don't need to be auth to get that) https://api.dailymotion.com/channel/music/videos

Comment: ok thanks but auth response is like this 
{"id":null,"scope":[],"roles":[],"username":null,"screenname":null}
the id is null, is there need to any parameter?

Comment: You need to pass the access token to get this information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136941/discussion-between-komal-and-zahid-rasheed).

Comment: Do you have an idea how to show all videos not particular music Chanel, Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by all videos?

Comment: i mean not any specific channel, i want to show the all channels videos

Comment: and right now it's showing data of page 1 and it's contain only 10 videos

Comment: This will get you videos (no channel or playlist): https://api.dailymotion.com/videos

Comment: And then you need to provide a field page:  http://api.dailymotion.com/videos?page=2

Comment: Is it possible to get video of localisation wise or country wise?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to make a GET request using https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking this library and sending the API key in your request header. This is one of the best networking libraries and very easy to implement. Use .addHeaders("token", "1234") to add API key in your request.